# Matrices such that $\det{(AB-pI_m)} = \det{(BA-pI_n)} \longrightarrow p|\det{(AB)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, divisibility

Let $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $B \in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{Z})$, $m<n$ be two matrices and let $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a fixed number such that $\det{(AB-pI_m)} = \det{(BA-pI_n)}$. Prove that $p|\det{(AB)}$.

I have tried expanding the determinants using the characteristic polynomial, but I have not succeeded in solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c_{M}(x)=\det(M-xI)$ be the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $M$. Observe that $c_{M}(0)=\det(M)$, and thus the free coefficient of the polynomial is the determinant of the matrix. This means that the statement

$$c_{AB}(p)=c_{BA}(p)$$

implies that $p|\det(AB)-\det(BA)$ (note that the polynomials have integer coefficients). Now since $n>m$ you have

$${\rm rank}(BA)\leq {\rm rank}(A)\leq m<n$$

for $BA\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$, so this matrix cannot be invertible and thus $\det(BA)=0$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I am impressed.

Comment: Is $p$ necessarily be $\pm1$ or any eigenvalue of $AB$(hence of $BA$)? Since $Ch_{BA}(x)=x^{n-m}Ch_{AB}(x)$ and by hypothesis $Ch_{AB}(p)=Ch_{BA}(p)$, we obtain that $p^{n-m}=1$ when $p$ is not an eigenvalue of $AB$.